# TypeScript Mapped Types - Is there a way to use interface value type as parameter of function type in mapped type?

Tags: typescript, types, mapped-types, typescript-types

I'm not sure how I might precisely describe my goal in words. Here is some code to explain what I would like to do:

```js
type validTypes = string | number

type item = Record<string, validTypes>

interface Test extends item {
  someint: number;
  something: string;
}

let test: {
  [P in keyof Test]: (arg: Test[P]) => boolean
} = {
  someint: (arg) => arg > 0,
  something: (arg) => arg == "hi"  
}
```

I'm trying to make the mapped type `[P in keyof Test]: (arg: Test[P]) => Test[P]` work, however, it's giving me the following error:

```
Type '{ someint: (arg: number) => boolean; something: (arg: string) => boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ [x: string]: (arg: validTypes) => boolean; someint: (arg: number) => boolean; something: (arg: string) => boolean; }'.
  Property 'someint' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '(arg: number) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(arg: validTypes) => boolean'.
      Types of parameters 'arg' and 'arg' are incompatible.
        Type 'validTypes' is not assignable to type 'number'.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

This is quite confusing to me, as `[P in keyof Test]: Test[P]` (without the function) seems to work. The error seems to appear when I try to use `Test[P]` as a parameter in the function type.

Comment: Unfortunately the resulting mapped type, `{ [x: string]: (arg: ValidTypes) => boolean; someint: (arg: number) => boolean;  something: (arg: string) => boolean; }`, is invalid. It says every method must accept the full `string | number` as an input, but `someint` only accepts `number` and `something` only accepts `string`.  Functions are *contravariant* in their parameter types, so the covariant mapping is unsound. Can you just suppress the index signature when you map like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wRA2YW)? If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the type of `test` (which you can inspect via IntelliSense) is:

```
let test: {
    [x: string]: (arg: ValidTypes) => boolean;
    someint: (arg: number) => boolean;
    something: (arg: string) => boolean;
}
```

And this is not a valid type.  Indeed, if you tried to create your own variable of that type explicitly, the compiler would complain:

```
declare let test2: {
    [x: string]: (arg: ValidTypes) => boolean;
    someint: (arg: number) => boolean; // error!
    //^^^^^ <-- not assignable to string index type '(arg: ValidTypes) => boolean'.
    something: (arg: string) => boolean;
    //^^^^^^^ <-- not assignable to string index type '(arg: ValidTypes) => boolean'.
};
```

The problem is that `Item`, and thus `Test`, has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) which gets mapped according to the same rule as the individual `someint` and `something` properties.  The index signature property becomes `(arg: string | number) => boolean`, meaning that every individual property needs to be a function that accepts an argument of type `string | number`.  But your `someint` and `something` properties become functions that only accept `number` and `string` respectively.  With [`--strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) enabled (part of the [`--strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict) suite of compiler options), functions need to be *contravariant* in their parameter types (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)). So if you widen the function parameter type you narrow the function type.  But the type mapping you apply is unfortunately *covariant*, and it produces an invalid type to which no value will be seen as assignable.

---

If you're only planning to access the `someint` and `something` properties of `test` then you don't really care about or want an index signature at all.  Indeed I'm not sure you want an index signature in `Test`.  So one way to proceed is to drop the index signature entirely:

```
type Satisfies<T, U extends T> = U;
type Test = Satisfies<Item,
    {
        someint: number,
        something: string
    }>;
```

Here `Test` has no index signature; it's just `{someint: number, something: string}`.  I've created a `Satisfies` helper type which acts kind of like a type-level [`satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator).  The above compiles, so `Test` is compatible with `Item`, but you're not *extending* it.  And so the following compiles:

```
let test: {
    [P in keyof Test]: (arg: Test[P]) => boolean
} = {
    someint: (arg) => arg > 0,
    something: (arg) => arg == "hi"
} // okay
```

Or, if you need `Test` to have the index signature you can build it in two parts:

```
interface TestWithoutIndexSignature {
    someint: number,
    something: string
}
interface Test extends Item, TestWithoutIndexSignature { }
```

And then make sure `test` maps over `TestWithoutIndexSignature` instead of `Test`:

```
let test: {
    [P in keyof TestWithoutIndexSignature]:
    (arg: TestWithoutIndexSignature[P]) => boolean
} = {
    someint: (arg) => arg > 0,
    something: (arg) => arg == "hi"
} // okay
```

Finally, if you can't change `Test` at all, then you can compute `TestWithoutIndexSignature` *from* it, using [key remapping in mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to filter out `string` from the keys:

```
type TestWithoutIndexSignature =
    { [K in keyof Test as string extends K ? never : K]: Test[K] }
/* type TestWithoutIndexSignature = {
    someint: number;
    something: string;
} */

let test: {
    [P in keyof TestWithoutIndexSignature]:
    (arg: TestWithoutIndexSignature[P]) => boolean
} = {
    someint: (arg) => arg > 0,
    something: (arg) => arg == "hi"
} // okay
```

The particular approach is up to you, but the goal here is not to let `test` have an index signature, since it only hurts you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwJYBMAq4IGcoF4pbABOSAdgOZQA+UpArgLYBGERAUG6JFAJLAQM8UAEoQAxgHsiKADyESFADSxEqDJCwA+DmX5EAZnDHQ02YFAgAPfqRQ4+AqAG82UNwQkMIugFy1GLEQA3K7uWJ4QwAAWZOR+8rEhAL4cbAiRUPyEfi7uUADaAApQZFAA1hAgEvpQpoQAun4AFHBEcbVmRfUAlHiaUEwSEulwpGxJQrlhEb5QLW29uP2tlP0ADIqhbuFe0bHNK4vLbXj4AEQxZ+McAPQAVFDp5lnAOVsFlvHEsY1zK37wZDoTBYI4DIYjUghPI7bykV5-Np+ejMVhgwbDCCjaHTXYxCgHJEEb4UdEQrFQ8ZQO43DgocQIVrQJ6ZMwAJjeeXyn2JCnIv3m7UBahBZMx2PesNmguRATRfXB4qhUBuNwsRCIUgAhO9VQA9A0GqAyAC0JtoEnMcCwWCQ5FIcCY6UyEl5sRKtismUwUAA5DKVED1NgxZDfQA6SURPYExHtBKkhUYyE4tz6w2G41mi1Wm12h1O6DAV0JyhkemWb3cf3-QMijShikR8YhDgOrxYMBGaAAEU1YAAovCkEQIAgQM53lxoABlODAJBYfRIbAyNDKACqFmsEFsODQ-XwG9TVZMZiEc4XS5XWBkDgYmzyeSmT6fUvhstRREfr7f0fx8YkuQ7x5EkmitnkLIvJyv5FB65SVNUHQNIS7R1MAXSNqM7wTPgL5-l40qHAqKxQOsP6vrCMbtIKYKkbg5yXDhKpqhIZRwCAqQpG2cAdl2xgiBA9LLqQ0D4borCGAJ6EAOpINEEh0MAPCepYM75vOdCjpOv4eIRH7+F+FEEZEAFfHyOHvBJBjdsh5hWDYdi8PwD52XJClKSpFbqfamnaU4UDcZBGTQTpsHFKUFRVDUsnyVEinKapPkOsAWkQI0IHuAGsUeYl3kaalo6YUm5LYaBkyZdsMwGbRJEnORlV6aZ+xxnRJwMVAFxIFc5WqlAbEcVxqScD6OXxZ5SUFWleDvAF+QANLwVFSHoVA1puhQ26OTgi0APy0BAABurBQH482-OhC31IFbD3KeblxQlXlWMlfnQHhUb6QiKKBCeVFmRt5DJNStIcFBZgAMwwW4cGRYhMVmO5415S9U2jgKtZjU9k2+YVEDFUsiqQlSH0wtVCK1YTpENWTeItZTxyUB1XVXEkQA)